# SML Error: Win32TextPrimIO:openRd: failed

Tags: emacs, sml, sml-mode

So I have 2 files, `file1.sml` & `file2.sml` both of which have correct code & I'm using a Windows operating system.

When I run Emacs and execute: use "file1.sml", it runs fine but then when I simply go to tab File->Close to close the file and then I drag `file2.sml` into Emacs and try to run it the same way, it gives the following error:

```
[use failed: Io: openIn failed on "file2.sml", Win32TextPrimIO:openRd: failed]
```

I tried restarting SML by doing c-c c-d but it's the same. So what I do is I quit Emacs and then start again and run `file2.sml` and it runs fine.

Why do I have to quit just to run another file?

Comment: Are both files in the same directory? They need to be in the working directory of the sml process. (It's often more convenient to use the SML mode commands, e.g. `Send buffer` and `Send region`, than to `use` files.)

Comment: No they're in different folders. You're right it works that way. But I remember a while ago I was able to run them fine though they were in different folders.. I don't know what happened :(

Answer (score 1):

there are few things you can right now do. 
1. save the file you created before trying to open it.
  i mean yes it sounds lame, but people new to programming ( as you tried to save it as "file.sml" , First save it. 
2. try to change \ to //
**Win32TextPrimIO:openRd: failed**

because it cant find it.